# Testing multiple beans implementing the same interface in spring

Tags: spring

I have an application in which I have multiple implementations for the same interface. At runtime, the desired implementation is selected by using `ConditionalOnProperty`.

I would like to have some way to make sure that when tests are being ran, the same test suite will run against all available implementations.

I believe this is possible either by using `TestConfiguration` or by overriding properties in the test, but I'm not sure what's the recommended way.